# Why is std:string not returning 0 on comparing sub strings of same text?

Tags: c++, stdstring

It's probably some simple oversight, but I'm perplexed on why the second compare doesn't return 0 in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string text =  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
    std::string text2 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

    int result = text2.compare(text);

    if (result == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "strings same" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "strings NOT same" << std::endl;
    }

    result = text2.compare(0, 10, text);

    if (result == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "strings same" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "strings NOT same" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) carefully. It will compare all of `text` against the 10 first characters of `text2`, which isn't equal.

Comment: @fredrik - got it!  Care to post your comment as answer?

Comment: You want `text2.compare(0, text.length(), text)`. Or, really, since all you're comparing for is equality of the substrings, not actually sort order, what you want is probably `std::equal`: `std::equal(std::cbegin(text), std::next(std::cbegin(text), 10), std::cbegin(text2), std::next(std::cbegin(text2), 10))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because compare function when passed the pos & len parameter, compares the whole of the first string with the second one. The first string is longer than part of the second string which you are comparing.

If you substring the first string also, then it will return true

```
result = text2.compare(0, 10, text, 0, 10);
```

The above call calls this overload

```
int compare (size_t pos, size_t len, const string& str,
         size_t subpos, size_t sublen) const;
```

subpos & sublen are pos & length of the first string to compare.